# Why did the Son Of Loki stop attacking Luke in The Ritual?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ritual

When Luke was chased down by the creature (called Son of Loki) in the movie The Ritual, I can't understand why the creature stopped attacking Luke when he fell to the ground and the creature made this gesture:

[image]

And what does the gesture mean? The creature could have carried Luke and impaled him to the tree branch during that moment.

Answer (score -1):

My interpretation of the scene is that the monster wants him to become a new worshipper, like the others from the hidden village.  He was marked earlier in the film as being "special" in some way.

Comment: This was my initial thought. I think everyone in the community was marked as "special". But if the creature wanted him to be added as a worshiper, why the creature killed some of the existing worshiper, like the woman as seen in the movie. If the creature just wanted to add more worshiper? 

What is special about Luke that the creature did not killed him or let say **why would the creature pursue Luke to become a worshiper and chose to kill the existing loyal worshipers**?

Comment: We don't know the history of the existing worhippers at all, but it could have been a case of  "you have failed me for the last time".  There may have been past mistakes we don't know about.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why he stopped is because Luke was marked in the first place for his suffering, but after Luke managed to overcome and face his own fear, then that made him of no use to the Son of Loki, who no longer wanted anything to do with him.

Comment: Please don't type in all caps.